# Upload text, image to database using textBox and fileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web

Greeting All
I'm trying to create an asp.net webpage using C# to Upload a details about products containing Product name, description, image and Product Number.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("ProductsImages/");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
            string name = "~/ProductsImages/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            string s = " insert into Products values('" + txtProductName.Text.Trim() + txtDescription.Text.Trim() + txtPrice.Text.Trim() + txtProductNumber.Text.Trim() + "','" + name + "')";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("Your File Has Been Uploaded");
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("You can upload only Jpg and png file");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        Response.Write("Please Select an file To upload");
    }
}
```

but when I start debugging it shows me an error : SqlException :
column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

However, my database design :
Column Name  |  Data type 
Name            nvarchar(50)
Description     nvarchar(50)
Price           nvarchar(50)
Image           image
Product_Number  nvarchar(50)

I don't know where is the wrong, in code or database??

Comment: BTW: read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert query is missing commas.

It should be:

```
string s = " insert into Products values('" + txtProductName.Text.Trim() + "', '" + txtDescription.Text.Trim() + "', " + txtPrice.Text.Trim() + ", " + txtProductNumber.Text.Trim())";
```

It would be better to do it with `SqlParameter`s, though.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
var queryInsert = "Insert Into Products Values (@productName, @productDescription, @productPrice, @productNumber)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", txtProductName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productDescription", txtDescription.Text.Trim());
```

...you get the idea.  You'd set up the parameters for each of them like I did above.

Comment: Thank you, but one more question plz, If I need to do it with SqlParameter I need to Create a Stored Procedure for it right?
Anyway, it does not matter if it was secure or not, it's just an assignment I have to do.
thank you I really appreciate your helping me !

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the line that you are creating your SQL Command. When the breakpoint is hit, inspect the value of the variable `s`. Your problem will become apparent: all you're doing is concatenating several of your fields into one single string. If you split them correctly, it should work.

On the other hand, you shouldn't be building your queries like that anyway. Use SqlParameters to correctly build and escape your queries.

Comment: If you want to see more about using parameterized queries, here's a simple example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Thank you man, I have tried to make a breakpoint but I could not read the error as well... thank you anyway..